# Insert new row into a table with values from another table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to triggers in MySQL, so sorry for any question that seems "really easy".

I have two tables: orders and orders_log

orders:

| order_id | (...) | product_id | (...) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | (...) | 103 | (...) |

oders_log:

| log_id | action | table_name | action_time | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

I want to create a trigger that when we INSERT a new row into "orders" table, it will generate a new row into orders_log with the log_id = 1...2..3... etc; and product_id = to product_id in table "orders". So that the orders_log would look like this:

| log_id | action | table_name | action_time | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | insert | orders | "now()" | 103 |

I'm trying to do this code:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS addrowlog;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER addrowlog
AFTER INSERT ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    insert into orders_log (`log_id`, `action`, `table_name`, `action_time`, `product_id`)
    VALUES  (NEW.log_id, 'insert', 'orders', NOW(), NEW.product_id);
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

But is gaves this error: Error Code: 1054. Unknow column 'log_id' in 'NEW.

And even when i just do this code:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS addrowlog;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER addrowlog
AFTER INSERT ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    insert into orders_log (`log_id`, `action`, `table_name`, `action_time`, `product_id`)
    VALUES  (log_id, 'insert', 'orders', NOW(), product_id);
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

When i try to add a row into 'orders' it will give me error "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails".

Can someone help me?

*EDIT:
Creation of the log table:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders_log` (
    `log_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `action` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `table_name` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `action_time` TIME DEFAULT NULL,
    `product_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`)
    );
```

(trigger created in the middle)

plus

````
ALTER TABLE `orders_log`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_log_3`
  FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`)
  REFERENCES `product` (`product_id`)
  ON DELETE RESTRICT
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```*
````

Comment: please show us the create table of the log table

Comment: I've edit the question, to show the creation of the log table. :)

Comment: your problem is clear you need to define an integer for log_id as it is not an auto_increment or uuid or anything else that can be genrated or is automatically generated

Comment: I've now done "`log_id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO-INCREMENT" and it still gaves me the errors. It is supposed to be done with the "NEW." or without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the auto_increment, you can remove the log_id from your insert or add NULL as value

```
CREATE TABLe orders (product_id int)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `orders_log` (
    `log_id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `action` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `table_name` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `action_time` TIME DEFAULT NULL,
    `product_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`)
    );
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER addrowlog
AFTER INSERT ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    insert into orders_log ( `action`, `table_name`, `action_time`, `product_id`)
    VALUES  ( 'insert', 'orders', NOW(), new.product_id);
END
```

```
INSERt INTO orders VALUEs(1)
```

```
SELECT * FROM orders_log
```

| log_id | action | table_name | action_time | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | insert | orders | 12:10:43 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wTaTATPQ)

Comment: Thank u so much! It really was an easy correction!